# Probability in the in the throw of a dice, two times.

Tags: probability

I have this statement:

> What is the probability of get at least a $5$ when throw a dice two
>   times?

Basically, my development was:

In the first throw i have: $2/6 = 1/3$

In the second throw i have $2/6 = 1/3$

With additive principle is equal to: $2/3$

But is a wrong answer, and the correct answer must be $11/36$

Then, ¿What is wrong in my development, and how i can do it?

Comment: The complementary event is throwing $≤4$ both times.  That has probability $(\frac  23)^2=\frac 49$, so the answer is $1-\frac 49=\frac 59$.  That's the same as what your method yields, once you remember that you have to subtract the cases where both throws are $≥5$ since you counted them twice.

Comment: I don't understand too much. What do you mean with throwing $< 4$ both and from where comes $(2/3)^2$ ?

Comment: Can you provide an answer, please? Im newbie in this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguous.  I read it as asking for the probability that at least one die shows at least a $5$.  Thus an outcome like $(1,6)$ would be a success.  It is also possible to interpret the question as asking for at least one die to show exactly a $5$.  My interpretation yields the answer $\frac 59$ as discussed below.  The other interpretation matches the desired answer of $\frac {11}{36}$.  I will discuss the second interpretation at the end.

Interpretation I:  For problems like these it is often easier to work with the complementary event.  In this case, that's "you throw $≤4$ both times."

The probability of throwing $≤4$ on a single throw is $\frac 46=\frac 23$.  The probability of doing it twice in a row is therefore $\left( \frac 23 \right)^2=\frac 49$.  It follows that the probability you want is $$1-\frac 49=\frac 59$$

There is nothing wrong with your idea, but you end up double counting the cases in which you throw $≥5$ both times.  To see that this overcounting is a problem, suppose you threw the die $4$ times.  Your argument would say that the probability that you get at least one $≥5$ is $4\times \frac 13>1$ which is obviously impossible.  To correct for this you must subtract the cases in which both throws are $≥5$.  That has probability $\left( \frac 13 \right)^2=\frac 19$.  Therefore your method, when corrected, yields $$\frac 23-\frac 19=\frac 59$$

Interpretation II:  Working off the complement again, the probability that any toss is a non-five is $\frac 56$.  Thus the probability that both are non-fives is $\left( \frac 56 \right)^2=\frac {25}{36}$.  Thus the answer, under this interpretation is, $$1-\frac {25}{36}=\frac {11}{36}$$

Comment: What would be the interpretation of the exercise, so that your answer was correct? I'm interested to know.

Comment: I have edited my post to explain both interpretations.

Comment: The add-on is useful, but how would you do without it? Since, the probability of obtaining a 5 is $(1/6)$ and in two throw is $(1/6) ^ 2 = 1/36$, but this is different of 11/36, why?

Comment: I don't understand.  First of all, $\left( \frac 16\right)^2$ is not $\frac 2{36}$.  Secondly, you now appear to be computing the probability that BOTH tosses yield $5$.

Comment: is true, thanks for your useful answer and help !!!

Answer (score 3):

Question might be oddly worded, it seems you want the roll of 5 to occur at least once, not getting at least the value 5. There are three possibilities for a success

1. 5 on first try, not 5 on second try
2. not 5 on first try, 5 on second try
3. 5 on first try, 5 on second try

The associated probabilities are

$$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{36};$$
$$\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{36};$$
$$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}.$$

With the additive principle, the probability of a success is $\frac{11}{36}$.

With the complementary approach, the desired probability is

$$1 - \Pr(\textrm{never getting 5}) = 1 - \frac{5}{6}^2 = 1 - \frac{25}{36} = \frac{11}{36}$$

Comment: Good way, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

when you throw two dice you have 36 possibilities 
in which possibilities in your favour are
$$ {(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(5,1),(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5),(5,6),(6,5)}$$
because you want at least a $5$ on the top face of  one of the dice

total of 11 possibilities

thus probability $=\frac{11}{36}$

Comment: because he doesn't want to get more than 5 I think you are mistaken the question is  he want at least one of the dice to show 5 on top face

Comment: Yes, I think there is an ambiguity in the question.  I read it as saying that you needed one die (at least) to be a $5$ or a $6$.  I understand your interpretation as well.  Note that the OP clearly interpreted it my way when it came to a single toss.

Comment: but by looking at his answer I predicted that he wants to calculate the probability when 5 shows on at least a dice

Comment: yes at least, James you are right

Comment: Yes, your answer matches the desired one.  And your interpretation makes perfect sense.  But I do think the question, as posed is ambiguous.

Comment: why don't the op edit it as when roll of 5 appears

Comment: Maybe, the translator is bad for me. I'm sorry, I speak spanish